# Python subprocess, give an input to a child process

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I made a program that checks a secret key. and another program that supposed to find the secret key. I managed to open a child process in the second program but couldn't send it an input. Here's the program that checks a secret key, `secret_key.py`:

```
SECRET_KEY = "hi"
current_key = 0

while not current_key == "exit":
    wrong_key = False
    current_key = raw_input("Enter the key or enter 'exit' to exit.\n")

    for i in range(len(current_key)):
        if i < len(SECRET_KEY):
            if not current_key[i] == SECRET_KEY[i]:
                wrong_key = True
        else:
            wrong_key = True

    if not wrong_key:
        print("the key is right!\n")
        current_key = "exit"

raw_input("Press ENTER to exit\n")
exit()
```

Now i made a .sh file to be able to run it in  a new terminal as a child process, `program.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

python Desktop/school/secret_key.py
```

And here's where i got stuck, `find_key.py`:

```
import subprocess

program = subprocess.Popen("./program.sh")
```

now I could't find a way to send `secret_key.py` the input it asks for.

Is there anyway I can send a string input to `secret_key.py` from `find_key.py`?

Comment: Why do you need program.sh running in a gnome-terminal?

Comment: My bad, don't need it. Removed and edited above. I just used interpreter to try it out and it messed up without a new terminal, but when i run it from `find_key.py` I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send input to and read output from a process opened via Popen, you can read from and write to the process using the process' `stdin` and `stdout` fields.  You do need to tell `Popen` to set up pipes, though:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([SPIM_BIN] + extra_args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pin = process.stdin
pout = process.stdout
```

And now you can write to `pin` and read from `pout` as you would with any old file descriptor.

Note that this will probably not allow you to connect to the `gnome-terminal`.  But it will allow you to connect to `program.sh`.

Comment: I'm writing process.stdout.write('hi'), but it im getting an error: "IOError: File not open for writing"

Comment: My bad, I listed `pin` and `pout` incorrectly.  You write to `pin` (the child process' stdin) and read from `pout` (the child process' output).  Fixed in the above.

Comment: Thanks, now I can send input. Though i don't quite understand how to use the `pout`, could you explain it more please? Also how can I send more than 1 input? for example if i have a program that asks for `a` and `b`: `a=raw_input()` and `b=raw_input()`?

Comment: pin and pout are file descriptors, so you can call write method on pin in order to send more input.

   pin.write("more input")

Using pout: pout.read()

Also you can call communicate method on process, send an input  and receive a output, even the error. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Look at the code I wrote above. After I give it the first input, `pin.write('hi')` - the correct key, it will ask me now to press ENTER to close the program. So i give it the second input, `pin.write('ok')`, it should exit and close the child process, but it gives me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/shcool/secret_key.py", line 24, in <module>
    raw_input("Press ENTER to exit\n")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr'